# In RMarkdown, can a floating TOC be placed on the right side of page

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I add a floating Table of Contents to my `R-Markdown` document, it always is on the left side of the page (with the content to the right), like so:

```
---
title: "some title"
author: "me"
date: "3/2/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---
```

[image: Default placing of floating TOC]

---

However, I'd like to move the floating TOC to the right side of the page. How can I accomplish this? The image below is what I'd like:

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the CSS chunk below (after YAML) and try increasing/decreasing the values of px (`right` and `margin-left`) for fine-tuning:

````
---
title: "some title"
author: "me"
date: "3/2/2020"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: TRUE
    toc_float: TRUE
---

```{css toc-content, echo = FALSE}
#TOC {
  right: 270px;
  margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.main-container {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```
````

Comment: That works, thank you! I'm going to link to this post when I open up a feature request for `RMarkdown` package on github, it'd be great if there was a simple option like `toc_side: right` in the `yaml`

Comment: That would be an handy feature.

Answer (score 3):

The R `Hmisc` package `hidingTOC` function does this, allows for changing some of the characteristics of the display, and provides buttons labeled 1 2 3 that the reader can click to show the table of contents to level 1, level 1-2, level 1-3.  No special `yaml` is needed; just have `require(Hmisc)` in your setup chunk and have the inline text sometime after that chunk: `r hidingTOC(buttonLabel="Outline")` or just use the default.  You can also just say `r Hmisc::hidingTOC()` as the inline R code.  Don't need to put these commands in a chunk; they render HTML which is automatically included in the document.